# Python requests: disallow cookies

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using Python requests:

```
import requests
image_url = my_url

headers = {'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/29.0.1547.76 Safari/537.36', 'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Encoding':'gzip,deflate,sdch'}
r = requests.get(image_url, headers=headers)
```

I would like the response to be the same as if I were sending the request from a browser that does NOT allow cookies to be set. The reason for this is that some sites give a different response depending on whether or not my browser allows cookies, and I need the non-cookie response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies are sent or not. If you don't set a cookie header, no cookie is sent. So the request in your question should be treated as sending no cookie.

The *server* sends a cookie in its response. If you set it in the next request, the server will recognize this. If you don't set it in the next request, the server will see that you don't accept cookies.

see http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#cookies

Comment: I'm not sending a cookie, but does the site realize that I do not want to accept any cookies? Let's say they have an if-else statement on their server that checks whether I can accept cookies.

Comment: @user984003: The server would set a session cookie and if it doesn't see that cookie in a *subsequent* request it must assume you don't want cookies to be set. There are also javascript techniques, but they cannot apply when you use a library like `requests`.

Comment: @user984003: But there is no foolproof way for a server to detect what your cookie settings are, anyway. And thus no (generic) way for you to set anything on the request to indicate that you don't accept cookies that'll work for all situations.

Comment: @user984003: if the server uses Javascript to detect cookies, a script would set a cookie client-side, then send an AJAX request to the server. If the server receives the request without a `Cookie:` header, then your browser is configured to not allow cookies. But each site can implement their own variation thereof and you'll have to figure out if your site does this manually, by looking at the site code and analyzing the traffic between a real browser and their site.

Comment: Further if @user984003is using a requests Session, he can call `del session.cookies` after each request to ensure no cookies are stored